# How to start an application as a child of a newly created explorer process?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm working on an application that resembles a kiosk. After the application starts, it creates a new desktop with limited capabilities. Using a key combo I can move back and forth between desktops. In order to inform the user about the desktop it's currently using, or any other information I've created an application, which is displaying balloon messages is System Tray area.

In the newly created desktop, I start an *explorer.exe* using  `CreateProcess` function, and providing the new desktop thru a `STARTUPINFO` structure, and I'm returning a handle for the process in a `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure.

Using the same technique I'm trying to start the icon tray application in the new desktop , providing the new desktop in the `STARTUPINFO` structure. The trouble is that, according to the task manager, the application is running, but the tray icon is not displayed.

My intuition says that in the new desktop, the icon is not shown because it's not a child of the new *explorer.exe* process, the *procexp* application from [live.systernals](https://live.sysinternals.com/%22systernals%22) is showing these two processes, on the same level in a tree representation.

Is there a way to provide an argument to `CreateProcess`, maybe the *explorer* process handle, so that the icon tray application starts as a child of this process?

L.E.: Here is the code that I use to create start the *explorer.exe* and the *icon tray* processes:

```
STARTUPINFO sInfoNT; /// startupinfo for the explorer.exe
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfoNT; /// process infromation for the explorer.exe
ZeroMemory(&sInfoNT, sizeof(sInfoNT));
sInfoNT.lpDesktop = L"threadDesktop"; /// setting the desktop for the process
pInfoNT = startProcess(sInfoNT, L"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"); /// starting the process 
if (!pInfoNT.hProcess)
    LOG(ERROR) << "Unable to start the new explorer process";
else
    LOG(INFO) << "Started the new explorer process";

STARTUPINFO sInfoTITD; /// doing the same thing for the tray icon application
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfoTITD;
ZeroMemory(&sInfoTITD, sizeof(sInfoTITD));
sInfoTITD.lpDesktop = L"threadDesktop";
pInfoTITD = startProcess(sInfoTITD, L"DesktopTrayIcon.exe");
if (!pInfoTITD.hProcess)
    LOG(ERROR) << "Unable to start the tray icon for the new desktop";
else
    LOG(INFO) << "Started the tray icon for the new desktop";
```

And this is the `startProcess` function:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION KioskLauncher::startProcess(STARTUPINFO startUpInfo, LPCTSTR lpApplicationName)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    if (!CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startUpInfo, &processInformation))
        MessageBox(0, L"Unable to start the process!\nThe path is broken!", L"Path Error!", MB_ICONERROR);

    return processInformation;
}
```

Comment: Try using [`SetThreadDesktop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250.aspx) to make sure the calling thread is running in the context of the desired desktop before calling `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: No, your intuition is wrong. Unfortunately you've asked the classic XY question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your really want to make the new Process a child of that other process, you have to use code injection. A search for `CreateRemoteThread` will give you plenty of reading material. The biggest problem is, that your process has to be the same bit-ness as the target. There are 3 ALTERNATIVE ways of using it:

- Dll injection (standard)
- Inject actual shellcode: Assembler code that will resolve all dependencies itself. (Will not work with EMET enabled)
- Copy a block of code from your application and fix the imports (Tricky)